# How can I remotely delete a file in document library in sharepoint online using remote event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, delete, remote-event-receiver

I want to write a program using remote event receivers to delete a file  within a document library. when `itemDeleted` event fire the that same file which was in another document library should be removed from the document library.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger file delete event, we need use remote event receiver with CSOM to achieve it. If you only want to delete a file in SharePoint Online document library in client side, we can use PowerShell with CSOM or PnP PowerShell to achieve it.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Remove-SPOFile()
{
  param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $FileRelativeURL
    )
    Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        #Get the file to delete
        $File = $Ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($FileRelativeURL)
        $Ctx.Load($File)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Delete the file
        $File.DeleteObject()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        write-host -f Green "File has been deleted successfully!"
     }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error deleting file !" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz/"
$FileRelativeURL="/sites/lz/Shared Documents/test.pptx"

#Call the function
Remove-SPOFile -SiteURL $SiteURL -FileRelativeURL $FileRelativeURL
```

**PnP PowerShell**:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz/"
$FileRelativeURL="/sites/lz/Shared Documents/test.pptx"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

    #Try to Get File
    $File = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If($File)
    {
        #Delete the File
        Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $FileRelativeURL -Force
        Write-Host -f Green "File $FileRelativeURL deleted successfully!"
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host -f Yellow "Could not Find File at $FileRelativeURL"
    }
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```